# Adding (SUM) a row in mssql with pivot

Tags: sql-server, sum, pivot

So I have this query here -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/90a35/1 where I'm displaying some data in a calendar type view. If I want to add another column (total) which will sum horizontally. i.e. for item x, I want to show sum of all months. How can I achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: add a CTE around your last query, sum your columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this; you can construct your sum columns dynamically in another variable just like you did for @cols

```
SET @sql = N';WITH temp as (SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ID, CONVERT(char(3), STA_IBF_WeekStartDate, 0) + ''-'' +  
      RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(STA_IBF_WeekStartDate)), 2) AS date, Forecast
FROM Table1) AS D
PIVOT(SUM(Forecast) FOR date IN(' + @cols + N')) AS P) SELECT *, [Sep-16] + [May-16] FROM temp;'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

I have added solution here in another [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/90a35/24)

Comment: This worked exactly the way I wanted. Thanks a lot for your help.